# Telerik ReportViewer - when using within a user control the control bar doesn't appear correctly

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-reporting

When using the Telerik ReportViewer control from inside a user control, the control bar (bar with navigation & exports buttons etc) doesn't appear to display correctly. Only the navigation buttons appear in the control bar itself. The other buttons (Export, Refresh, Print, & Close Parameters) all appear below the control bar, each on a new line.

If I do the exact same in a normal page (rather than user contorl), it appears fine.

Any ideas?

P.S. I'm using IE 7 and the Telerik 2009 Q3 ASP.NET AJAX suite.

Comment: When you contain the `ReportViewer` inside a `UserControl`, are there any extra html tags surrounding the `ReportViewer`? My initial thought was there were perhaps differences in markup and resulting `CSS` applied...

Comment: No, it just appears on its own. I'll do some more comparisons between the html in the stand-along page and the user control version. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

OK, have sorted this problem.

Someone had put this in our global.css:

table 
   {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
   }

WTF?!?!

Thanks KP, I should have looked at this sooner.